# Renaming child items after moving til another directory - powershell

Tags: powershell

I have been handed over a Powershell script that searches a folder for new items, if there are any items, it sends an email with the items attached and moves them to another directory. However, my problem is that the files in the first directory will always be named the same so i would need to rename the files as i move them to the back-up directory with date and time to prevent the older files from being overwritten. How would i go about the code to do so?

I should probably add that i have no experience with powershell, hence the probably stupid question.

```
$Folders = @( 'C:\Users\PAT\Desktop\attachement testfolder'
                )
$DestFolder = 'C:\Users\PAT\Desktop\Backup folder'

$EmailList = @( 'recieving-email@hotmail.com'
             )

$From       = 'pat@email.com'
$Subject    = 'New files'
$SMTPServer = '111.111.111.111'

#  Get new files
$NewFiles = $Folders | Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse

#  If there are an new files...
If ( $NewFiles )
{
#  Add the file count and file names to the body of the email
$Body = '$($NewFiles.Count) new files attached'
$NewFiles | ForEach { $Body += $_.Name + "" }

#  Send the email with attachments
Send-MailMessage -From $From -To $EmailList -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -
BodyAsHTML -Attachments $NewFiles.FullName -SmtpServer $SMTPServer

#  Move the emailed files to the destination folder
$NewFiles.FullName | Move-Item -Destination $DestFolder -Force 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up figuring it out

I changed the Move-Item with this code

```
#  Rename files with current date and time and moves them to backup directory
$NewFiles | ForEach-Object {
Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination "C:\Users\PAT\Desktop\Backup 
mappe\$($_.BaseName,(Get-Date).ToString("MMddyyyy hhmmss"),$_.Extension)"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, as an alternative:

```
$NewFiles | Rename-Item -NewName { "$(Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMddHHmmss")-$($_.Name)" } -PassThru | Move-Item -Destination $DestFolder
```